# What is the correct (internal) voltage range for a RPi 4?

Tags: power, voltage

When running `vcgencmd measure_volts` on older RPi's, a normal reading is 1.2v

However, on my new RPi 4, the voltage reading is: 0.8648v

Does this indicate a power issue, or is this normal, and the RPi 4 operates on a lower core voltage than earlier versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RPi 4 core voltage scales dynamically with frequency in a range of 0.8V to 1.4V (going above 1.25V requires setting [`over_voltage`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md) in `config.txt`, and going above 1.35V voids your warranty). For an idle CPU, a value around 0.85V is pretty normal.

Comment: is this a suitable method for testing power input health? (I have 2x12Vx7Amps) batteries in series connected to a dual motor HAT, with internal voltage regulator feeding the RPI. What can I expect if left unchecked?

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT a "voltage reading" (because the Pi has no analog capability) this is reporting the voltage configured. The Pi like most modern CPU adjusts voltage/clock to optimise performance.

Don't worry about it - unless you are designing computers this is of no consequence.

Answer (score 0):

yes the difference is power requirements. You may be using the old power supply for the new RPi 4 The old req.'d 2.5A supply & the new req's 3.0A (min.) to run properly!
I hope this answers your question 
all the best,
Pat.
Please check RPi 4 spec. for conformation details.